nginx unit - create path based routing for applications
I play around with nginx unit to run node.js applications.
Now i want that a single http server/listener for both applications and forward the incoming request based of the uuid in the path or custom http header like x-app: 417fd251-a356-437c-81e1-7d967c18d0dd.
My "deployment" config looks currently like this:
{
    "listeners":{
        "127.0.0.1:8301": {
            "pass": "applications/417fd251-a356-437c-81e1-7d967c18d0dd"
        },
        "127.0.0.1:8302": {
            "pass": "applications/c4bb95ab-802e-4283-9b22-0abc978803f5"
        }
    },
    "applications": {
        "417fd251-a356-437c-81e1-7d967c18d0dd": {
            "type": "external",
            "executable": "/home/marc/.nvm/versions/node/v20.11.1/bin/node",
            "working_directory": "/home/marc/projects/playground/nginx-unit/",
            "arguments": [
                "--loader",
                "unit-http/loader.mjs",
                "--require",
                "unit-http/loader",
                "server.mjs"                
            ],
            "environment": {
                "DB_HOST": "192.168.122.123",
                "UUID": "417fd251-a356-437c-81e1-7d967c18d0dd"
            },
            "isolation": {
                "namespaces": {
                    "cgroup": true,
                    "credential": false,
                    "mount": true,
                    "network": true,
                    "pid": true,
                    "uname": true
                }
            }
        },
        "c4bb95ab-802e-4283-9b22-0abc978803f5": {
            "type": "external",
            "executable": "/home/marc/.nvm/versions/node/v20.11.1/bin/node",
            "working_directory": "/home/marc/projects/playground/nginx-unit/",
            "arguments": [
                "--loader",
                "unit-http/loader.mjs",
                "--require",
                "unit-http/loader",
                "server.mjs",
                "c4bb95ab-802e-4283-9b22-0abc978803f5"
            ],
            "environment": {
                "DB_HOST": "172.18.52.29",
                "UUID": "c4bb95ab-802e-4283-9b22-0abc978803f5"
            },            
            "isolation": {
                "namespaces": {
                    "cgroup": true,
                    "credential": false,
                    "mount": true,
                    "network": true,
                    "pid": true,
                    "uname": true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

curl http://localhost:8080/417fd251-a356-437c-81e1-7d967c18d0dd should go to app "417fd251-a356-437c-81e1-7d967c18d0dd"
server.mjs
#!/usr/bin/env node

import { createServer } from 'node:http';

const ENVIRONMENT = {
  UUID: "",
  DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "blog.settings.prod",
  DB_ENGINE: "django.db.backends.postgresql",
  DB_NAME: "test",
  DB_HOST: "127.0.0.1",
  DB_PORT: "5432"
};

// override default env, with external set env
// but keep the defaul object untouched
// so we can iterrate over it
process.env = Object.assign({}, ENVIRONMENT, process.env);


const ENVS = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(process.env).filter(([key, value]) => {
  return Object.keys(ENVIRONMENT).includes(key);
}));


const server = createServer((req, res) => {

  let {address, port} = server.address();
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

  res.end(JSON.stringify({
    header: req.headers,
    url: req.url,
    method: req.method,
    server: {
      host: address,
      port
    },
    args: process.argv.splice(2),
    environment: ENVS
  }, null, 2));

});


server.listen(3000, '127.0.0.1', () => {
  let {address, port} = server.address();
  console.log(`HTTP Server listening on http://${address}:${port}`);
  console.log(`Hello from UUID=${process.env.UUID || "undefined"}\r\n`)
});

I tried it with the following config, but it complains "Unknown variable "app_name" in the "pass" value.":
{
    "listeners": {
        "*:8080": {
            "pass": "routes"
        }
    },
    "routes": [
        {
            "match": {
                "method": "GET",
                "uri": "^/(?<app_name>[^/]+)"
            },
            "action": {
                "pass": "applications/$app_name"
            }
        }
    ]
}

I have the concern that i cant use custom variables from regex, because they are no mentioned: https://unit.nginx.org/configuration/#variables
Tried:
"pass": "applications/${app_name}"
"pass": "applications/$request_uri"
"pass": "applications/${request_uri}"
"pass": "applications/${uri}"

Always get a 404 instead of json response from a app instance.
Any idea or hint?
Thanks in advance
